# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file 9

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I am creating my first material design android app in android studio.Got following error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.versatilenetwork.cofinding, PID: 2224 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.versatilenetwork.cofinding/com.example.versatilenetwork.cofinding.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class item
```

This error i got at runtimme

My MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.versatilenetwork.cofinding;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private Toolbar toolbar;                                  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); 
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                  

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>


    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:text="hello world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I have difined tool_bar.xml in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Help me out of this error

Comment: Post your full logcat.

Comment: @Gitaram Kanawade see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of define toolbar id here

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>
```

Remove that and add it to **tool_bar.xml** file

change to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**final Code :**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>


    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:text="hello world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**tool_bar.xml** file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```